# Android: How a library module use the class defined in application module?

Tags: android, dependencies

```
/MyProj
|---/MyApp (application module)
    |----/MyData
         |----class Person
|---/MyLib (library module)
    |----/MyMethod
```

In MyData I define a class Person:

```
public class Person{
}
```

How can I refer to Person in MyMethod of MyLib which is a library module?

I don’t want to redefine Person in MyLib.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have that in your myLib you need to add the app module as a dependency in your myLib WHICH IS WRONG and makes a circular dependency.

In order to prevent circular dependency in layered design patterns they place the models classes in a seprate module so all other modules can use them.

What i suggest you is to make a model module and put all your data models in that then you can access that only by this sequence of dependency:

App -> myLib -> ModelModule

This way both app and myLib can use your model classes. (You just need to have myLib as App dependency and ModelModule as MyLib dependency)

Another simple way is just to move your models to myLib.

Comment: Yes, I had try to add app module as a dependency of MyLib, but it suggest an application module can not be a dependency. Also, it will make a wrong circular dependency.  I can't move Person to MyLib or a new library for the class had call some methods that defined in MyApp. I can't move all for it involve a lot of code.

Comment: There is always a trade off. If you want a clean code you must pay for it ;) if uset class is a data Model class it shouldnt do any function in it. You must move the complete model layer. No other clean way believe me